# Indy 10 email attachment appears in body

Tags: indy

I've upgraded an existing email sending program from Indy 9 to Indy 10.  This works fine in our test environment but on a clients site the attachments are appearing in the body of the email. Their SMTP server is adding a footer to the email and adding `<html> ... </html>` tags around the whole thing, which is causing this issue. The previous version on Indy 9 worked fine for this client.

Here is an example of the email we are sending:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="gcJJK3Qk5C6XIV9FEwfRcK=_EH4Oq32hqE"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Thu, 1 Oct 2020 00:02:29 +0100
Message-Id: <20201001000278.SM78660@B-P-S0308-APP1>

This is a multi-part message in MIME format

--gcJJK3Qk5C6XIV9FEwfRcK=_EH4Oq32hqE
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

Body text appears here.

--gcJJK3Qk5C6XIV9FEwfRcK=_EH4Oq32hqE
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
    name="PDA Audit.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename="PDA Audit.pdf"

JVBERi0xLjINCjEgMCBvYmoNCjw8IC9UeXBlIC9DYXRhbG9nIA0KL1BhZ2VzIDMgMCBSIA0KL1Zp
ZXdlclByZWZlcmVuY2VzIDw8IA0KPj4NCj4+IA0KZW5kb2JqDQo1IDAgb2JqDQo8PCAvVHlwZSAv
<more lines here>

--gcJJK3Qk5C6XIV9FEwfRcK=_EH4Oq32hqE--
```

Is there anything wrong with this?

I note that the boundary no longer contains the `=_NextPart`, so I'm wondering if the code on the server has been badly written and is expecting to find this. Has anyone else had a similar issue?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this email. This is the email you are sending out to the server, right? Can you show what the *server-modified* email looks like that you are having trouble viewing? What does its parsed email body look like?  Note for loading MIME emails into `TIdMessage`, any MIME part that has a `Content-Type` that is not `text/...` or `multipart/...`, or has a `Content-Disposition` that is `attachment`, should never appear in a body text, it should be a `TIdAttachment` object in the `TIdMessage.MessageParts`

Comment: Also, neither Indy 9 nor 10 create MIME boundaries with `=_NextPart` in them.  That `NextPart` text is not part of the official MIME spec. The actual values of boundaries are arbitrary and implementation-specific, they are just required to be unique and distinguishable from the rest of the body text.  Though the spec does *suggest* including `=_` in boundaries (to avoid conflicts with `quoted-printable` encoded body text). Some MIME libraries use `=_NextPart` (or a variation of it), Indy uses just `=_`, the rest is random.

Comment: The _server-modified_ message it too big to post in full, but here is a summary

`Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii";
 boundary="PaZhQrP6jw7biezBU1O3mklOfBHSWxH=_1"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Thu, 8 Oct 2020 13:01:22 +0100
Message-ID: <69dc89fb-5873-4f92-938f-4db82c6f541a@EXCH-HUB01.cc.xxxx.local>
Return-Path: Test-MaintenanceServices@xxxx.ac.uk

X-Headers here

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dus-ascii"=
>
</head>
<body>

Original email here including content types

<p>Footer appears here</p>
<p></p>
 </body>
</html>`

Comment: So the server has converted the whole email to html rather than just the text part.

Comment: The copy of Indy 9 that shipped with Delphi 7 definitely contained `=_NextPart`. Constants  declaring three different MIME boundaries appear in IdMessageCodeMIME.pas and all start with `=_NextPart`.  The constants are then used in IdMessageClient.pas

Comment: I appreciate that `=_NextPart` is not part of the standard

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.  We were allowing Indy to decide on the `Content-Type` which worked if we only sent an email with an attachment.  If a previous email was just text the `Content-Type` was set to `text/plain`.  When the email with the attachment was then sent Indy thought the `Content-Type` was already set so did not change it.  Setting the `Content-Type` correctly solved the problem.